# How to write python program to import csv data file into a relational database without inserting duplicate entries

Tags: python, sql

I am using the following python code to import CSV data file into a relational database.

However, my code is inserting duplicate rows (with unique primary key ID) in all dictionary tables. How do I update my code to get rid of the dupes.

```
import csv
from cs50 import SQL

open ("shows.db", "w").close()

db = SQL("sqlite:///shows.db")

db.execute("CREATE TABLE shows        (id      INTEGER,      title    TEXT,       PRIMARY KEY(id) )")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE genres       (id      INTEGER,      genre    TEXT,       PRIMARY KEY(id) )")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE shows_genres (show_id INTEGER,      genre_id INTEGER,    FOREIGN KEY(show_id) REFERENCES shows(id),   FOREIGN KEY(genre_id) REFERENCES genres(id) )")

with open("Favorite TV Shows - Form Responses 1.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        titles = row["title"].strip().upper()
        show_id = db.execute("INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES (?)", titles)
        for genre in row["genres"].split(", "):
            genre_id = db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO genres (genre) VALUES (?)", genre)
        db.execute("INSERT INTO shows_genres (show_id, genre_id) VALUES(?, ?)", show_id, genre_id)
```

Raw Data - Favorite Movie Poll:

| Date Time | Show | Genre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2021 9:00:00 | The Office | Comedy |
| 10/1/2021 9:03:00 | Fringe | SciFi |
| 10/1/2021 9:08:00 | The Office | Comedy |
| 10/1/2021 9:10:00 | Games of Thrones | Action, Fantasy |

Example of current output (has dupes) - Genre Dictionary Table:

| Genre_ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Comedy |
| 2 | Sci-Fi |
| 3 | Comedy |
| 4 | Action |
| 5 | Fantasy |

Desired Output - Shows Dictionary Table:

| Show_ID | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | The Office |
| 2 | Fringe |
| 3 | GoT |

Desired Output - Genre Dictionary Table:

| Genre_ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Comedy |
| 2 | Sci-Fi |
| 3 | Action |
| 4 | Fantasy |

Desired Output - Shows_Genres Table:

| Show_ID | Genre_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 (GoT) | 3 (Action) |
| 3 (GoT) | 4 (Fantasy) |

Comment: Query the db for the row before you write it to check it isn't already there.   and **please don't bold everything, it really hurts my eyes**

Answer (score 0):

You can create your tables using a `UNIQUE` constraint on the appropriate column(s) ([UNIQUE constraint tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-unique-constraint/)). This prevents duplicates from being inserted.

Note that when you try to insert a duplicate it will come back with an error. You simply need to catch this error so that it doesn't crash your program.
In this case, if you need the ID, you can then simply query the table using a `WHERE` clause to get the existing row.

Also, it's important to note that running a query and then your insertion will not guarantee uniqueness if anything else might be editing the database. It's possible that another thread/process could insert the value in question between your query and insertion.